# Downloading image through bitmapsource block rest of API calls

Tags: wpf, sails.js, restsharp, bitmapsource

I have strange problem with my API calls.

I'm writing WPF application with usage of `RestSharp`. All my calls to API uses RestSharp.

I have a Photos module, which downloads only urls of photos. From that URLs I'm creating BitmapSource objects.

I have a strange problem that all of API calls during loading of photos get timeout.

It's hot I'm creating BitmapSource objects:

```
Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
```

I have binded collection of Images to `ItemsControl` with `Image` control inside.

Have you ever got similar problems? Is that because of BitmapSource or RestSharp?

To fullfill the question: We're using Node.js + Sails.js on server side.

Comment: That constructor of Bitmap source will download the image asynchronously, not sure what is causing it to hold up other threads.

Comment: Yep, I know that images are downloaded asynchronously. But why other API calls are blocked. I have been trying to find that out for couple of hours, without success

Comment: I have added details about our server implementation

Comment: Are the APIs that are blocked RestSharp APIs or WPF APIs?

Comment: I see no `RestSharp` here. I wonder if you actually know where the UI thread is blocking. I suggest using a profiler to find out.

Comment: I decided to not sharing my RestSharp calls code, it's just a simple calls. Does not matter which call I invoke, it's just not working. @MagikM18, I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Aron, Seems that my UI thread is not blocking, my UI is working fine. It looks like all other threads are blocked.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I reread your question, I see what you were saying now. It's probably that RestSharp prevents you from running multiple requests simultaneously, probably to avoid corrupting non-thread-safe resources continually required by the download. I have never used RestSharp, but if this is the case you might want to report it to its developers as a bug

Comment: More likely you are downloading from the same source. .net limits the number of requests per hostname.